accessing .env file unseccessfully in node.js
I was working on a discord chatbot for some practice and try to access some environment variable in .env file. However , some how I was not able to access those variables with some following code:
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

console.log(process.env.A);
console.log(process.env.B);
console.log(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);

A="123"
B="456"
DISCORD_TOKEN="some-token"

My Directory
When I run these code , I found that they cannot be accessed and point to a node module call process
The variable pointed
Output(not expected)
Finally , thanks for everybody's help since I am a very beginner for some API project like this.

The file should just be .env, not process.env. And the variables don't "point to a module"

To load your .env files, try using the process.loadEnvFile('path_to_env') method.

In your "My Directory" screenshot, it looks like you named your env file process.env. It needs to be named just .env
